# While importing excel of data at approx 60,000, I need to show the progress bar in my blade view of laravel accordance with my importing of data

Tags: laravel, progress-bar, maatwebsite-excel

I am importing my data using maatwebsite sharing you snippet for it,

```
row['entrydate'] = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['entrydate'])->format('Y-m-d');
Client::create($row);
```

This is importing file code, time at which this button is triggered I am directly calling my route and function which redirect to my above code.

**I want to show the progress bar as per my data is importing from excel for ex: data consist of 1,00,000 reocords or 1,000 records, That progress is need to be displayed in Blade View in Laravel.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lottie Player](https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@0.4.0/dist/lottie-player.js).

**View :**

```
<lottie-player id = "loaderImg"
  autoplay
  controls
  loop
  mode="normal"
  src="https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_UJNc2t.json"
  style="width: 320px"
>
</lottie-player>
```

If it is ajax request then you can use below code :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
   $("#loaderImg").css("display", "block"); 
});
```

If it is button action event :

```
$(document).on("click",".btnAction",function() {
   $("#loaderImg").css("display", "block"); 
});
```

Comment: I want to show progress bar with exact execution of time that takes for importing my data through excel using maatwebsite that can be **N** number of records 1thoushand, 1Lakh...